# How to wrap a soap service into the rest api?

Tags: java, rest, soap

I have built a web service using java in eclipse. And called it in soap ui. now I want to wrap this soap service into rest api. Can anyone help me?

Design a simple Restful java base API that “wraps” around the SOAP API.

Comment: which framework did you use for SOAP?

Comment: @mkysoft Apache Axis2